# Meetup API finding groups where user is co-organizer

Tags: php, meetup

Looking through meetups API for groups, http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/groups/ , supposedly I can query groups where I am a member or organizer. Query member_id with an ID returns groups, but querying organizer_id returns nothing.

Am I missing something or require some other access? I'm positive that the ID I'm using, mine, is co-organizer of a few a groups.

And I'm using this PHP library: https://github.com/blobaugh/Meetup-API-client-for-PHP

Comment: dose it work in the console? https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/2/groups

Comment: How did you determine your ID?